# Flutter. How to draw these designs in a container

Tags: flutter, dart, geometry, widget, containers

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFstJ.jpg)

Please tell me how to draw these encircled geometrical lines in a container .

After drawing a container widget how should i draw these custom geometrical designs in a container

Comment: The entire background there is actually an image. This one https://pub.dev/static/hash-qs2p3tk4/img/hero-bg-static.svg

Comment: Can you need exactly picture like this ....if you ask then i will create this for you

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Square'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SquarePercentIndicator(
              width: 140,
              height: 140,
              startAngle: StartAngle.bottomRight,
              reverse: true,
              borderRadius: 10,
              shadowWidth: 1.5,
              progressWidth: 5,
              shadowColor: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
    );
  }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use `figma` to style these types of lines and shapes, and export it as `png` image.

If you want to code the entire drawing, it is not recommend, but it can be achieved, using rounded bordered containers, but there would be lot of limitations